# Problema de memoria en micropython

Tags: python, manejo-de-memoria

Estoy usando una placa SiPy (de pycom) y al implementar en mi proyecto un par de ficheros nuevos, obtengo un error al ejecutar mi código en una linea que importa una clase propia que no daba problemas:

```
MemoryError: Memory allocation failed, allocating 136 bytes
```

He leído sobre problemas similares y no he conseguido solucionarlo.
He realizado un **os.fsformat("/flash")** para tratar de limpiar la placa y re-subir mi código o quitar la línea en cuestión, pero la primera no dio resultado y la segunda solo consigue sortear esa linea y obtener el mismo fallo poco más adelante.

```
print("Thanks people")
```

Comment: A tu pregunta le faltan muchos detallas, no queda claro por que e está produciendo el error en cuestión. Esto por que no adjuntas el código que te está generando el error. Te recomiendo leer [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), te informarás de la manera adecuada de formulra preguntas.

Answer (score -1):

El mensaje puede ser por dos causas:

**Tu programa necesita más memoria de la disponible.**

Ocurre cuando el total de memoria que necesitas en un momento dado supera la memoria disponible. En este caso debes reestructurar tu programa para reducir el consumo de memoria.

**No has reciclado la memoria.**

Cuando creas un objeto, Python usa memoria desde la RAM disponible (*heap*). Cuando borras (*del*) el objeto o éste deja de estar accesible, Python **no** devuelve de inmediato la memoria usada.

En forma normal, microPython recicla la memoria sólo cuando le falta memoria para crear un nuevo objeto. El reciclado no siempre es oportuno (o la memoria puede estar fragmentada), y se producen errores como el que mencionas.

Para evitar estos errores, debes activar manualmente el reciclado dentro de tu programa, usando *gc.collect()* en lugares *apropiados*. Esta es una operación costosa, que puede interferir con otros procesos críticos en el tiempo (captura de sensores, I2C, comunicaciones), motivo por los cuales microPython lo posterga tanto como puede.

¿Cuales son los lugares apropiados? En general, luego de retornar de una función que genera objetos masivos, o en aquellos puntos del programa donde no vas a hacer nada (antes de un *time.sleep()*, por ejemplo).

Otro tip: Si necesitas crear y destruir un objeto masivo, hazlo en una función separada, para garantizar que el objeto se ha vuelto inaccesible y que Python puede detectarlo y eliminarlo.

He aquí un trozo relevante de un servidor web que devuelve un json masivo. Este json se crea y retorna dentro de "send_status". Asi se el json vuelve inactivo y candidato para reciclar memoria tan pronto la función retorna.

Para forzar el reciclado, se llama a *gc.collect()* tan pronto se cierra la conexión con el cliente:

```
def send_status(conn):
    """ Envia el estado de la aplicacion en format JSON.
        Incluye estadísticas de temp/humedad minuto a minuto por 24 horas
    """
    
    ... obtención y manipulación de los datos requeridos ...
    status = dict(temperature=control.temperature,
                  humidity=control.humidity,
                  uptime=util.uptime(),
                  memfree=str(gc.mem_free()),
                  date=util.time2str(),
                  relay1="on" if machine.Pin(control.relay_gpio[0]).value() else "off",
                  relay2="on" if machine.Pin(control.relay_gpio[1]).value() else "off",
                  tasks=[task.to_dic() for task in control.timer.tasks],
                  samples=[sample.to_ISO8601() for sample in control.stats.stats()])

    conn.send(ujson.dumps(status))


def server():
    """ Servidor Web.

        Entrega status del sistema y acepta operaciones sobre los relays.
        Atiende sólo una conexión a la vez; no se espera más que un cliente.
    """
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    sock.bind(('', 80))
    sock.listen(1)

    ''' El servicio nunca se detiene, pero se puede caer.
        En tal caso, el thread principal reinicia este thread.
    '''
    while True:
        try:
            conn, addr = sock.accept()
            request = conn.recv(1024).decode('UTF-8')
            ... Otros procesos no relevantes para este ejemplo ...    

            send_status(conn)
            conn.close()
            gc.collect()
        except OSError as err:
          ... etc ....
```

Comment: Debido a la malformación de la pregunta no se puede tener claro el causante del problema, por lo tanto no puede tener una respuesta válida. Te recomiendo leer [como responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Saludos ;)!